# Вывод элементов из многомерного массива foreach

Tags: php, массивы, foreach, вывод

Массив

```
    $library = [
    'authors' => [
        'john_makkormik@example.com' => [
            'name' => 'Джон Маккормик',
            'email' => 'john_makkormik@example.com',
            'birthYear' => 1972,
        ],
        'martin_robert@example.com' => [
            'name' => 'Мартин Роберт',
            'email' => 'martin_robert@example.com',
            'birthYear' => 1957,
        ],
        'charles_levin@example.com' => [
            'name' => 'Чарльз Левин',
            'email' => 'charles_levin@example.com',
            'birthYear' => 1985,
        ],
    ],
    'books' => [
        [
            'title' => 'Чистый код: создание, анализ и рефакторинг',
            'author' => 'martin_robert@example.com',
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Девять алгоритмов, которые изменили будущее',
            'author' => 'john_makkormik@example.com',
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Идеальный программист',
            'author' => 'martin_robert@example.com',
        ],
                [
            'title' => 'Еще одна книга',
            'author' => 'charles_levin@example.com',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Нужно вывести в формате: Книга <Название книги>, её написал <ФИО автора> <Год рождения автора> (<email автора>).

Я могу вывести данные  из 'authors' и 'books' в двух разных foreach, но не могу вывести в одном, создав одну строку. Могу так:

```
foreach ($library['authors'] as $author) {
   var_dump ($author['name'] . $author['birthYear'] . $author['email']);  
}

foreach ($library['books'] as $book) { 
   var_dump ($book['title']);  
}
```

Пробовала разные варианты такого вывода, но ничего не вышло:

```
foreach ($library as $key => $value) {
     foreach ($value as $key) {
         var_dump ($key['authors'] . $key['title']);
     }  
}
```

Как вывести в формате: Книга <Название книги>, её написал <ФИО автора> <Год рождения автора> (<email автора>)?

Comment: а они соответствую друг другу по индексам?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($library['books'] as $book) { 
   $author = $library['authors'][$book['author']];
   echo $book['title'] . $author['name'] . $author['email'];  
}
```

[Фиддл](https://3v4l.org/sTNoP).