# вывод из массива php нужных данных в html-разметку

Tags: php, html

дан массив и html-разметка

```
$library = [
    'authors' => [
        'john_makkormik@example.com' => [
            'name' => 'Джон Маккормик',
            'email' => 'john_makkormik@example.com',
            'birthYear' => 1972,
        ],
        'martin_robert@example.com' => [
            'name' => 'Мартин Роберт',
            'email' => 'martin_robert@example.com',
            'birthYear' => 1952,
        ],
        'martin_fauler@example.com' => [
            'name' => 'Мартин Фаулер',
            'email' => 'martin_fauler@example.com',
            'birthYear' => 1963,
        ],
    ],
    'books' => [
        [
            'title' => 'Чистый код: создание, анализ и рефакторинг',
            'author' => 'martin_robert@example.com',
            'year' => 2013,
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Девять алгоритмов, которые изменили будущее',
            'author' => 'john_makkormik@example.com',
            'year' => 2011,
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Идеальный программист',
            'author' => 'martin_robert@example.com',
            'year' => 2011,
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Шаблоны корпоративных приложений',
            'author' => 'martin_fauler@example.com',
            'year' => 2002,
        ],
    ],
];

<p>Книга <Название книги>, ее написал <Фио автора> <Год рождения автора> (<email автора>)</p>
```

задание: "в отдельных абзацах выведите книги: Книга <Название книги>, её написал <ФИО автора> <Год рождения автора> (<email автора>)"
помогите разобраться, как правильно выводить? скорее всего я даже не правильно рассуждаю, но я делал так:

Книга <$library['books']['title']>, выдавало ошибку, попробовал сделать через foreach, но тоже не получилось... может хотя бы направите в нужном направлении?

Comment: Где вы регулярно берете это задание? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1379593/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-foreach/1379607#1379607

Comment: спасибо за ссылку, объясните, пожалуйста, как его интегрировать в html

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так...

```
foreach ($library['books'] as $book) {
    echo "<p>Книга $book['title']</p>"
}
```

А вообще для начала соберите все данные в удобоваримый формат где в каждом item массива будет храниться вся инфа по книге и ее автору, потом по этому собранному массиву пробегаемся и выводим